# How do I fit my X - Axis labels on my plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, forecast

I cant seem to find a way to fit my x labels in the right way on my plot.
Can someone help ?

here is the code and the output is in the picture

Code:

```
sns.lineplot(x="ds", y="y", data=df_new, hue="Type", marker="o")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to rotate your xlabels, which makes your plot more readable. Try:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="ds", y="y", data=df_new, hue="Type", marker="o")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
```

And then plotting your data.